# ProFont not showing in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts

My favorite coding font, [ProFont](http://www.tobias-jung.de/seekingprofont/), does not show up in the list of fonts in Visual Studio 2010. Shows up fine in VS 2008 on the same box. Any ideas? I'm using Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `.FON` (ancient bitmap-font format) version of ProFont? I know WPF does its own font rendering; it may be that FON fonts are no longer supported.

[Grab the TTF version](http://www.tobias-jung.de/seekingprofont/) and I believe it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. It doesn't look nearly as nice as it does in 2008. I think I'll stick with Consolas for 2010.